# How to know what is the server processing time for a request in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have attached screen shot of sample result in table view. Out of these which parameter depicts the exact server processing time for that request?[This is Table view of sample result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N9Ip.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

JMeter treats server as a "black box" so it knows nothing about server processing time, roughly you can measure it by subtracting `Connect Time` from the `Latency` (a synonim for [TTFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_byte)), however it will contain the time required for the packets to travel back and forth so it will be slightly (or significantly) bigger than the server processing time, depending on the physical distance of the JMeter load generator(s) from the system under test.

So the only way to collect server processing time is measuring it on the server side, i.e. from the [server access log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_log) or application log. The values can be obtained remotely and plotted using i.e. JMeter PerfMon Plugin.

References:

- [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)